# Cron Job Produces No Output

Tags: cron, postfix, awk

I am using the following cron entry to clean my Postfix queue:

```
* * * * * mailq|awk ' /^[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]*.*MAILER-DAEMON$/ {print $1}'|tr -d '*'| xargs -rn1 /usr/sbin/postsuper -d > output.txt
```

However, this is producing no output.

- It works when I simply execute it in terminal.
- The cron daemon is running.
- Other jobs are working.
- There is write permission to output.txt

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it run successfully directly from terminal? IF so, use full path to the binaries..

Comment: @heemayl Yes, it does. When you say binaries, do you mean mailq and awk?

Comment: I found that mailq seems to work without the full path. When I try * * * * * mailq|/usr/bin/awk ' /^[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]*.*MAILER-DAEMON$/ {print $1}'|tr -d '*'| xargs -rn1 /usr/sbin/postsuper -d > output.txt, it still does not work

Comment: Are you sure? anyway i am not familiar with mail tools but you have used `>` redirection operator, that means successive runs will overwrite the previous one..so what if the first run generates desired output and the next runs just clears the file as no desired mail in the queue..

Comment: Try deleting the file. Is it recreated? If so, you know the job is running, just nor producing output. I don't know `postsuper` but are you sure it's supposed to produce output? It might only be printing to stderr. What happens if you run `postsuper -d` with a valid argument and redirect its output to a file? Is that file still empty?

Answer (score 1):

Please replace `>` by `2>&1 >>`, test this:

```
* * * * * mailq|awk ' /^[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]*.*MAILER-DAEMON$/ {print $1}'|tr -d '*'| xargs -rn1 /usr/sbin/postsuper -d 2>&1 >> output.txt
```

UPDATED:
You can set the path to output.txt complete, for example, Please try this:

```
* * * * * mailq|awk ' /^[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]*.*MAILER-DAEMON$/ {print $1}'|tr -d '*'| xargs -rn1 /usr/sbin/postsuper -d 2>&1 >> /var/log/output.txt
```

I hope help you.

Comment: I did this. Still getting an empty file.